# Copying email addresses from Excel to Gmail into the BCC line

Tags: gmail

I used to be able to copy a column of email addresses (with a comma at the end of each) from Excel into the BCC line of a Gmail message.

Now when I try to copy the column of emails, only the first line copies into the BCC.

Can anyone help?

Comment: Do you still face those problems?

Answer (score 3):

I entered an email address with a comma at end

1. in each cell in one single column (`A1, A2, A3 ...`)
2. in the first cell of each column (`A1, B1, C1 ...`)
3. in one cell (`A1`)

See screenshot:
[image]

I tried both ways by copy and pasting into `BCC`, `CC` and `TO`, everywhere it pastes properly.

I think you might be performing something wrongly.